# WPF Window flash notification?

Tags: wpf, flash, window

I've started using the XCEED MessageBox recently, which uses custom chromes (<-I think that's their name) for the title bar, and it seems that there is no handling for the case when a dialog window (or modal dialog in Win32 terms) needs to flash in response to the user trying to click on the (disabled) parent window.

The flashing border animation is usefull to notify a user that he must respond to a dialog before continuing and to give a hint on which dialog window is that.

Is there a way to get notified when a window needs to perform the flash animation in WPF or set XAML triggers for it?

Comment: I don't think there's a XAML only way to do this. I think you (and I) will have to resort to WinAPIs. Let me know when someone clarifies this. I want to know as well.

Comment: OK. :)
But, how can I let you know?

Comment: make a comment in this question starting with @ and my name